# Error: Please define stage 'create_pg_db' in your Zappa settings

Tags: django, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, zappa

**Intro:** I am deploying a django app to AWS lambda severlessly using zappa. My RDS instance has a postgres database. I am watching [rich jones djangocon video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixRZfVBn_A8&t=911s) on how to deploy django app severlessly using zappa. So far I have managed to reach the part where I need to add a database to my project. I have already done `pip install zappa-django-utils` and added it to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now when I try to run

`zappa manage create_pg_db production` I get the error:

```
Error: Please define stage 'create_pg_db' in your Zappa settings.
```

I even tried `zappa manage create_pg_db` I am still getting the same error

**Below is how my zappa_settings.json file looks:**

```
{
    "production": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "django_settings": "Cool.settings",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "cool",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "cool-7dsfsdf5",
        "project_directory": "/tmp/code",
        "slim_handler": true,
        "vpc config": {
            "SubnetIds": [
                "subnet-3132ss13b",
                "subnet-321321319",
                "subnet-2c2313223",
                "subnet-5ljlkjljd",
                "subnet-132121357",
                "subnet-f925f9c7"
            ],
            "SecurityGroupIds": [
                "sg-a9asdasd"
            ]
        }
    },
    "production_ap_northeast_1": {
        "aws_region": "ap-northeast-1",
        "extends": "production"
    },
    "production_ap_northeast_2": {
        "aws_region": "ap-northeast-2",
        "extends": "production"
    },
    ... All regions..
}
```

How do I define stage `create_pg_db` in your Zappa settings. Does anyone know the steps ahead of this.

**Results with** `zappa manage production create_pg_db`

```
(Venv) $ django-admin --version
1.11.15
(Venv) $ zappa manage production create_pg_db
[START] RequestId: c621321b9-611d-4457-9c23-f65465653dd Version: $LATEST
[DEBUG] 2019-01-28T04:55:05.629Z c6231b9-611d-4457-9c23-f6064654653dd Zappa Event: {'manage': 'create_pg_db'}
No module named 'django': ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 580, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 248, in lambda_handler
    return handler.handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 399, in handler
    from django.core import management
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[END] RequestId: c621321b9-611d-4457-9c23-f65465653dd
[REPORT] RequestId: c621321b9-611d-4457-9c23-f65465653dd
Duration: 1.85 ms
Billed Duration: 100 ms 
Memory Size: 512 MB
Max Memory Used: 512 MB

Error: Unhandled error occurred while invoking command.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `zappa manage production create_pg_db`? As in the stage should come before the command? https://github.com/Miserlou/zappa-django-utils/blob/master/README.md#creating-a-postgres-database

Comment: @MilanCermak I tried that see output above

Comment: I don't know enough about zappa to help you here, but it seems `django` is not available in the Lambda container - how did you package and deploy your app? Check if `django` is available there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one stage defined which is called **production**. If you want to name your stage **create_pg_db** then it would like this:

```
{
    "create_pg_db": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "django_settings": "Cool.settings",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "cool",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "cool-7dsfsdf5",
        "project_directory": "/tmp/code",
        "slim_handler": true,
        "vpc config": {
            "SubnetIds": [
                "subnet-3132ss13b",
                "subnet-321321319",
                "subnet-2c2313223",
                "subnet-5ljlkjljd",
                "subnet-132121357",
                "subnet-f925f9c7"
            ],
            "SecurityGroupIds": [
                "sg-a9asdasd"
            ]
        }
    },
    "production_ap_northeast_1": {
        "aws_region": "ap-northeast-1",
        "extends": "production"
    },
    "production_ap_northeast_2": {
        "aws_region": "ap-northeast-2",
        "extends": "production"
    },
    ... All regions...

    "production": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "django_settings": "Cool.settings"
    ... MORE settings...    
}
```

At the end you can add more stages and then use the stage for your deployment. For example, you can have a *develop* stage that deploys your code to a development environment and a *production* stage that deploys your code to the production environment.